# Why doesn't the active answer tab include upvotes activity?

Tags: support, answers, up-votes

For example, if we upvote this answer, it doesn't affect that.

It will be useful in some answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51723852/5033247) that got less attention because it is not shown at the top.

Comment: Because voting activity isn't an important enough activity to warrant someone looking at a given post again.

Comment: What's the "active answer tab"? You mean "active question"?

Comment: @yivi https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8Ev0.png

Comment: @user400654 in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51723852/5033247) case?

Comment: @SmartManoj in that case, the question should be deleted. voting activity isn't relevant.

Comment: Thanks @Glorfindel (particularly for the helpful arrow). I didn't think of that this since we already have the ability to sort by votes. I thought they meant [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VRz9.png). Makes less sense to me now I guess.

Comment: Why does it matter which answer was voted last?

Comment: Because somebody put an effort to analyze all recent answers and voted the best if the accepted answer is outdated @yivi

Comment: Someone voted whatever they liked, that's all. Individual votes are meaningless, only the aggregate can give you some approximation to a meaningful signal. If at all.

Comment: But most people just go with accepted answer or the top 2

Comment: But "active" already put the newest (or the one edited most recently) at the top. So according to your theory, the newest answer (and the accepted one) would get all the votes, right?

Comment: I spoke for the in-between ones https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319113/feature-request-auto-star-option#comment323088_319114

Comment: SmartManoj, please don't completely change a question (particularly if it's not being well received) by adding a different question in an attempt to improve your vote score. You ***can*** improve the same question but you can't alter the question. If you have a new question (which apparently you do, and it's a better one) then ask a **new** question. There can usually be a single question asked per question (or a few very similarly related ones), adding a completely different question invalidates the value of prior votes and makes existing answers seem incomplete (affecting their votes).

Answer (score 10):

Because that is not the purpose of that tab. Its purpose is to see which answers were recently updated, so that users can review edits (maybe somebody introduced something harmful which needs to be reverted; maybe somebody made a brilliant edit and now the post is worthy of an upvote).

Comment: doesn't that include comments?

Comment: No, comments are second class citizens, much less important than posts.